# display options in react search box when clicking on the box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying the following code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactSearchBox from 'react-search-box'

export default class App extends Component {
  data = [
    {
      key: 'john',
      value: 'John Doe',
    },
    {
      key: 'jane',
      value: 'Jane Doe',
    },
    {
      key: 'mary',
      value: 'Mary Phillips',
    },
    {
      key: 'robert',
      value: 'Robert',
    },
    {
      key: 'karius',
      value: 'Karius',
    },
  ]

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactSearchBox
        placeholder="Placeholder"
        value="Doe"
        data={this.data}
        callback={record => console.log(record)}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

and it works really. However the search options only show when I start typing in the searchbox. What I am trying to do is when the user clicks in the search, show them some options, Can you help with understanding how to achieve that.

there is a method called

```
onFocus - A function which acts as a callback when the input is focussed.
```

which does get called when I click in the search box, but I am not able to work out how to display the options in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'

export default class App extends Component {
state = {
  selectedValue:null
}

 data = [
 {
  label: 'john',
  value: 'John Doe',
 },
 {
  label: 'jane',
  value: 'Jane Doe',
 },
 {
  label: 'mary',
  value: 'Mary Phillips',
 },
 {
  label: 'robert',
  value: 'Robert',
 },
 {
  label: 'karius',
  value: 'Karius',
  },
 ]

 render() {
 return (
  <Select
  options={this.data}
  isSearchable
  value={this.state.selectedValue}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
  )
}
}
```

If you want to display a dropdown with search option I would recommend using react-select library. However your data should be in the form of an object like this {label:' ',value:' '}. This component takes an isSearchable prop that allows us to search the dropdown as well as select an option manually. Hope this helps!